# Showing copied data in Infragistics wingrid

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I'm using Infragistics wingrid in my C# winforms app.
I need to be able to copy column values from an excel sheet and paste it in this datagrid.The grid should show these new values in the cells.How do I achieve this?What code changes would be required?

I tried it and only one cell value gets updated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `InitializeLayout` do:

```
e.Layout.Override.AllowMultiCellOperations = AllowMultiCellOperation.All;
```